# Can "child support" be translated differently from "pension alimentaire pour enfants"?

Tags: traduction, droit-et-justice, enfants, finance

[translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=child%20support&op=translate) gives "pension alimentaire pour enfants" as the translation for child support. However, "child support" goes much beyond the financial support for purchasing food items. Can  "child support" be translated differently from "pension alimentaire pour enfants"?

Comment: From the entry for *pension alimentaire* in the Grand Dictionnaire Terminologique: "On distingue la pension alimentaire pour enfant (child alimony, child support, child support payment, child support payments) et la pension alimentaire pour ex-conjoint (spousal alimony, spousal support, spousal support payment, spousal support payments)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une *pension alimentaire* ne se limite pas aux dépenses d'alimentation. C'est le terme français qui correspond à l'expression anglaise « *child support* ». On ne précise en général pas « pour enfants » parce que l'expression « pension alimentaire » est suffisamment spécifique comme ça.

Voir par exemple la définition de [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/alimentaire) (années 1870) :

> Terme de jurisprudence. Pension alimentaire, somme fixée par autorité de justice pour frais de nourriture et d'entretien. Provision alimentaire, somme attribuée par les juges à l'une des parties jusqu'à la fin d'un procès.
> Se place toujours après le substantif.

L'« [entretien](https://www.littre.org/definition/entretien) » peut couvrir toutes les dépenses de la vie courante, y compris le logement, les vêtements, etc.

La [définition](https://www.caf.fr/glossaire/pension-alimentaire) de la [CAF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caisse_d%27allocations_familiales_(France)) (organisme chargé entre autre de surveiller le versement des pensions alimentaires) est :

> une somme d'argent versée à un des parents pour l'entretien et l'éducation d'un enfant.

Un autre site du gouvernement français indique que la pension alimentaire existe parce que

> Tout père et toute mère doit nourrir, vêtir, loger et élever son enfant, même majeur.

Le mot *alimentaire* vient bien du mot latin *[alo](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/alo#la)* qui signifie principalement nourrir, mais même en latin le terme peut plus généralement référer aux besoins vitaux. Ce sens plus large a existé en français mais a presque disparu du vocabulaire courant. Il survit dans quelques expressions comme *pension alimentaire*, mais aussi par exemple un *travail alimentaire* (un travail choisi par quelqu'un qui préfèrerait une occupation plus intéressante, par exemple un artiste, mais qui fait ce travail pour avoir de l'argent non seulement pour se nourrir mais aussi pour ses autres besoins vitaux).

Le [dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/aliment) signale au 18e siècle un sens plus large du mot *aliment* en français lorsqu'il est au pluriel :

> ALIMENS, au pluriel, se dit généralement de tout ce qu'il faut pour nourrir & entretenir une personne.

Dans sa [8e édition (1932)](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/aliment), ce sens n'est plus considéré qu'un terme de droit.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting part on the etymology + alimens!

Comment: En tout cas en Belgique on parle toujours de débiteur et de créancier d'aliments pour désigner qui doit ou a droit à une pension alimentaire, respectivement.